# How to import bootstrap partially in angular application?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I am using bootstrap by adding the CSS class in "styles" from angular.json, it overriding some angular material CSS styles globally. Is there any way to use bootstrap in only some selected components which will not impact global styles?

Comment: Using Bootstrap + Angular Material at the same time sounds like asking for trouble

Comment: i am working with some material, and i can tell you that sometimes it is a problem to add my css to it, and i am very afraid to imagine what can happen if i were to add bootstrap as well XD maybe [this]() can help you https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/angular-flex-layout-introduction/, this directive with material, are working well for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to import bootstrap partially (not globally) in an angular application you should import bootstrap file in a component CSS (component.css) file like this:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: Does it have any impact in overall application performance? Means, can importing the bootstrap styles multiple times in whole app affect the performance?

Comment: Yes, importing bootstrap specifically in the components or modules would impact the performance. If you really need to style your pages locally then you can go for it otherwise better to set the style globally.